# Counting integers with k large prime divisors

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, factorization

If $x \ge y \ge 1$ are real numbers and if $k$ is a positive integer, take $\Phi_k(x, y)$ to be the number of integers $\le x$ with exactly $k$ prime factors and no prime factor $\le y$. If $y$ is pretty big, and if $k$ is pretty big, and if $\ln \ln x - \ln \ln y$ is pretty close to $k$, then I'm fairly sure that 
$$\Phi_k(x, y) \approx \frac{e^{-\gamma}x }{\ln x} \frac{(\ln \ln x - \ln \ln y)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$
with $\gamma$ the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

This result seems almost exercise-level basic and, in the case that $\ln \ln y = o(\sqrt{\ln \ln x})$, is given as a literal exercise in [a paper of Tenenbaum](http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/51/3/385.extract). However, my current approach to proving it for larger $y$ involves taking a detour through [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.3494.pdf) to prove, for any positive real $\alpha$,
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\,\, \frac{1}{(\alpha k)^k} \cdot\int_{\substack{x_1, \dots, x_k \ge 1\\ \sum x_i \le e^{\alpha k}}} \prod_{i \le k} \frac{dx_i}{x_i} \approx \frac{e^{-\gamma/\alpha}}{\Gamma\big(1 + \frac{1}{\alpha}\big)}.$$

This seems a bit like overkill to me. Does anyone know of a good source for asymptotics/error on $\Phi_k(x, y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotics of such integral may be obtained by applying appropriate Tauberian theorems. If we denote $x_i=e^{t_i}$, then your integral is $F(e^{\alpha k})$, where $F(T)$ is a volume of the set $\{t_i\geqslant 0,\sum_{i=1}^k e^{t_i}\leqslant T\}$. For getting some information of $F(T)$ we take some $\lambda>0$ and integrate $\exp(-\lambda\sum e^{t_i})$ over $[0,\infty)^k$. At first, this integral factorizes and equals $(\int_0^\infty \exp(-\lambda e^t)dt)^k=(-Ei(-\lambda))^k$. On the other hand, it equals 
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\mu\{\exp(-\lambda\sum e^{t_i})\geqslant x\}dx=
\int_0^{\infty}\mu\{\exp(-\lambda\sum e^{t_i})\geqslant e^{-s}\}e^{-s}ds=\\
\int_0^\infty F(s/\lambda)e^{-s}ds.
$$
Asymptotics of $F(T)$ for large $T$ should be defined by asymptotics of $\int_0^\infty F(s/\lambda)e^{-s}ds$ for large $\lambda$ under some assumptions like monotonicity. (Not finished yet.)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for this result, as I was, this is treated in Alladi's paper, "[The distribution of ν(n) in the sieve of Eratosthenes](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/33/2/129/1593431?redirectedFrom=fulltext)", Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 33 (1982), no. 130, 129–148.

In particular, it is shown there that if $\exp((\log_2 x)^3)<y<\sqrt{x}$, $u=\frac{\log x}{\log y}$ and $\xi = \frac{k}{\log u -\gamma}$ and $r>0$ is fixed, then uniformly for $1\leq k <r \log u$,

$$\Phi_k(x,y) = \frac{xe^{-\gamma\xi}}{\log x \  \Gamma(1+\xi)} \cdot \frac{(\log u)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\left(1+O_r\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log u}}\right)\right).$$

The conjecture above follows since if $\log \log x-\log \log y \approx k$ then $\xi \approx 1$.

See also Balazard, Michel, "[Unimodalité de la distribution du nombre de diviseurs premiers d'un entier](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=AIF_1990__40_2_255_0)", Ann. Inst. Fourier (Grenoble) 40 (1990), no. 2, 255–270.  Where a slightly more cumbersome version is given that is applicable in a greater range of $u$.